# Ubunutu 18.04 LTS fresh install - Stuck at grub OS selection screen

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS from a bootable USB stick in my HP Spectre x360 which already has Windows 10. I did a normal installation with additional drivers option and everything went fine. After I restarted the system grub loader screen came up and it just got stuck there. I was not able to use the arrow keys to make a selection. No errors whatsoever. Things I've tried -

1. Tried minimal installation without additional drivers
2. Tried boot-repair from live Ubuntu

Most of the articles I found online while researching this issue pointed to purging Nvidia drivers. But in those cases users were able to get till Ubuntu loading logo. But I never got there. Also grub did not end up in rescue mode. So could that be a different issue?

Boot repair - http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QgMypHsCjn/

Any pointers to troubleshoot?

Comment: None of the keys are working once I get to the grub screen. The system gets frozen exactly in that screen (which is - https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCPLl.png)

Comment: Again, as I said none of the keys work in that screen. The entire keyboard is not working. Even the 10 second timer is not running in the bottom. It is just hung up.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI from HP for your system and updated firmware for NVMe SSD? Looks like you have Intel video, not nVidia? That also can be a setting to turn on different video if you really have nVidia. check UEFI settings for USB ports. YOu may need full access or similar setting.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I was just able to fix it. All I did was enable Legacy Boot from the system bios and boom the grub loader worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just enabled legacy boot from System Bios and the grub loader started working. Here is the link on how to do it.

https://support.hp.com/ie-en/document/c03653226